# Is there any loan that leverage tax for H1b holders?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, loans, h-1b-visa

I am here in US through H1B. I have a decent amount of loan back in India. Also I am paying a lot in Tax here.

Is there any way I can get any loan here in US and pay off my loan in India and reduce the tax here in US as well?

Note: I am in H1B. I don't own any house here in US.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can get any loan here in US

yes you can try and get a personal loan.

> and pay off my loan in India

Yes you can pay of the loan in India.

> and reduce the tax here in US as well?

This is not possible. Only certain types of loans get tax benefits.

Answer (score 1):

### Is there any way I can get any loan here in US and pay off my loan in India and reduce the tax here in US as well?

1. Buy a house and get a mortgage. That will reduce your taxes.
2. Take out a (low interest) HELOC to pay off your existing loans.

However, you'd need a 20% down payment, and if you had that much money you'd have already paid off your loans.

So... echoing @Dheer, the answer is "no".